# Is there a way to select schema in python hdbcli dbapi?

Tags: python, hana, python-db-api

According to [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/hdbcli/), parameters needed to connect to HANA database are host, port, user and password.

```
from hdbcli import dbapi
conn = dbapi.connect(
    address="<hostname>",
    port=3<NN>MM,
    user="<username>",
    password="<password>"
)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

This selects username as schema by default. Is there a way to specify schema name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no connection property that would allow setting/switching to a specific schema.

What you can easily do, however, is to switch to your intended schema right after creating the connection:

```
conn = dbapi.connect(
    address = 'hxehost',
    port = '39013',       # connecting to the HANA system, not the DB directly
    user = '...',
    password = '...',
    databasename = 'HXE', # using the DB name instead of a port number
    #key='USER1UserKey', # address, port, user and password are retreived from the hdbuserstore
    encrypt=True, # must be set to True when connecting to HANA Cloud
    sslValidateCertificate=False # True HC, False for HANA Express.
)

#If no errors, print connected
print('connected')

c1 = conn.cursor()
c1.execute("SET SCHEMA R_C")       # <-- here we set the current schema for the connection
c1.execute("SELECT current_schema FROM DUMMY") # <-- checking the current schema
rows = c1.fetchall();          # <-- [('R_C',)]
```

This works well for me and I don't see any side-effects besides the additional command to set the schema.